# PubSub binder - Failed to create consumer binding; retrying in 30 seconds

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-gcp

I am using Google Cloud PubSub binder to consume event. Currently we did all the testing with Pubsub emulator and everything work perfectly fine.
**Issue**:
Now currently we want to stop the binding at the start of the application until I finailze Pubsub topic and subscription details. I found there is an option to do that which is **autoStartup: false**
But it doesnt work as I thought it will. The reason I found in the **AbstractMessageChannelBinder ** class in **doBindConsumer ** method that code will try to provisionConsumer destination before checking autoStartup property.

**Question**
What is the right wayto disable or stop binder instead of removing the binder pubsub dependency or stop retrying so we will not get " failed to create consumer binding every 30 second" error message?

try added autoStartup to false

Comment: The resources provisioning has nothing to do with an auto-startup. Did you try something like `spring.cloud.stream.gcp.pubsub.default.consumer.auto-create-resources=false`? https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/3.4.0/reference/html/index.html#configuration-3

Comment: Yes, I am using autoCreate false. After this PubSub binder does not create new subscription but it still try to connect to find the exisitng subscription. 

In case my case becuase there is no subscrition ready/created yet I want binder to skip everything. So when things are ready I will update the application.yaml to setup accoringly

Comment: PubSub finder method "provisionConsumerDestination"
[Link](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/main/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/stream/binder/pubsub/provisioning/PubSubChannelProvisioner.java)